# What does the thing between "class" and the class name in VC++ mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bridj

I have a third-party VC++ based DLL I want to use in a Java project, along with its header. I figured out BridJ is a good solution for this, but the header is so complex that JNAerator chokes at it and just freezes at 100% CPU, finally bailing out with `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. So I have to write the bindings for the needed things from the header myself.

Now, I have to guide BridJ via annotations. For this, I looked at the header and I found a part looking like the following which I do not understand:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
  class SomethingStrange TheClass {
    public:
      TheClass();
    // more
  }
}
```

So, what I want to know: What does `SomethingStrange` mean here? Is this another child namespace? And how do I wire this up correctly in BridJ?

Comment: Do you have a specific value for `SomethingStrange`?

Comment: Can you show what `SomethingStrange` is in the actual code?

Comment: I cannot because I am not allowed to publish part of the header.

Comment: I'll punt an answer: it's quite common when building DLLs

Comment: In Visual C++ _SomethingStrange_ can be only a storage-class specification _declspec(...)...

Comment: I will try to only state the namespace in my BridJ class and just ignore the `SomethingStrange` then.

Comment: Then I guess you should bring the question to the people that provided you the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building a DLL, `SomethingStrange` will boil down to `__declspec(dllexport)`.

When *using* that DLL, it will boil down to `__declspec(dllimport)`.

They allow a class declaration to be used by both the author and users of a particular DLL.

What they "boil down to" is normally controlled by compiler flags controlled via the project settings.

Comment: You seem to be right, I just ignore the `SomethingStrange` and it seems to work so far

Comment: Right click on it though and see what it's defined to.